# How to import Maven project when can't find its parent pom?

Tags: java, maven, jax-ws

I download latest version of JAX-WS Reference implement at here:

https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxws/archive/JAXWS_2_2_10_FCS.zip

Then I unzip to a directory, import use IDE (IntelliJ IDEA), but `pom.xml` can't resolved: https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxws/blob/c5f21c3da833d41c1e012bdafef6302f69011a74/jaxws-ri/pom.xml

It can't resolve parent pom:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-ri-bom-ext</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.10-b140803.1500</version>
    <relativePath>boms/bom-ext/pom.xml</relativePath>    
</parent>
```

I want import this Maven project success, what should I do?

Comment: can you show the full error message ?

Comment: The error message is: `Can't resolve directory boms/bom-ext/pom.xml` . You can't download, then import to IDE, you will see it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to clone and then open/import the repository. Attached are screenshots [image]

Then you will be able to use it in IntelliJ
[image]

Comment: Thank friend, What is the difference between download/clone in this case? Because, I believe that, download a **release version** is better than a **in-working** version. Do you really see file `pom.xml` (at top-level) resolve all dependencies success?

Comment: Hi Do , The super pom dependency (boms/bom-ext/pom.xml) does get resolved , no errors in that. I did not however try executing any lifecycle task. On the lifecycle , i did get some CNFE errors on aether plugins. You are right , a release version is indeed better